# Moving or clicking objects around in a list

Tags: c#, jquery, list, razor

I'm trying to create a way of moving "chapters" around. My problem is that I can't get my head around to how. If any of you guys have an idea or example of how you've done it, it would be great.

I was thinking something like a list. Where you can drag or click "chapters" around.

like this:

- Chapter A

  - Chapter A.a

    - Chapter A.a.a
    - Chapter A.a.b
  - Chapter A.b
- Chapter B

  - Chapter B.b
- Chapter C

The thing is, if I just have a button for moving up and down, then I would need additional buttons for when moving to a chapter from A to C.

PS: The project is in `.cshtml`.

Edit: each child-chapter has a value which holds the id of its parent. When moving around this id will change, and then be saved when the user i happy with the current order.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a re-usable, sorting widget to simply order elements around, and then have 3 (in this case): one for the chapters, one for the sections and one for the sub-sections. You can show and hide the corresponding widget based on what's currently selected.

Furthermore, you can show each item as an accordion (again, one for chapters, one for sections, etc.). By default you can reorder the chapters. Once you select one, you can view and reorder its sections, and once you select a section... well, you get the idea.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a great widget for this called 'sortable'.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NVBrP/1/) is a working jsfiddle that does what I think you are looking for.  Use the [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) and [connected lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) examples.

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 3
      <ul class="sortable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 3a</li>   
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 3b</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 3c</li>
      </ul>          
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 4
    <ul class="sortable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 4a</li>   
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 4b</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 4c</li>
      </ul> 
 </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Chapter 5</li>
</ul>

$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      connectWith: ".sortable"
    });

    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Comment: I like what it is doing, but it can't add a child-chapter to a parent-chapter that doesn't already have a child. Can this work with new id's? I'm thinking maybe have the parent id added to all the childs in some form of value

Comment: I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVBrP/2/) to use the `dropOnEmpty` parameter.  I also added some styles.  It's not pretty, but it does provide a way to drag chapters around.  You have to drag them onto that little gray thing sticking out to the right.  Of course, you will have to change the styling to make this approach look better.